# SQL Server to liquibase connection building

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

1. I'm using the following properties file

```
[driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath: ..\\Program Files\\sqljdbc_12.6\\enu\\jars\\mssql-jdbc-12.6.0.jre11.jar
changeLogFile: D:\\Liquibase\\databaseChangeLog\\dbchangelog.sql
url: jdbc:sqlserver://<SHIVAM-LAPTOP>:1433;databaseName=liquibase;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=false;]
```

and setting it as default properties for liquibase.

2. Authentication used is windows authentication.
3. using java version as follows

> C:\Users\shiva>java -version
> java version "1.8.0_202"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

4. When running the following command

```
[c:\Liquibase>liquibase --defaultsFile="C:\Liquibase\liquibase.properties" update]
```

I am getting the following error

```
[Starting Liquibase at 11:57:02 (version 4.25.1 #690 built at 2023-12-18 16:29+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.25.1
Liquibase Open Source 4.25.1 by Liquibase
ERROR: Exception Details
ERROR: Exception Primary Class:  SQLServerException
ERROR: Exception Primary Reason: The TCP/IP connection to the host <SHIVAM-LAPTOP>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "<SHIVAM-LAPTOP>. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
ERROR: Exception Primary Source: 4.25.1

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://<SHIVAM-LAPTOP>:1433;databaseName=liquibase;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=false; with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  The TCP/IP connection to the host <SHIVAM-LAPTOP>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "<SHIVAM-LAPTOP>. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

For more information, please use the --log-level flag]
```

Please help me in resolving this

Comment: Aside... did you realize that you're using a jre11 driver on Java 1.8?

Comment: Dod you have an SQL Server instance installed on the host that's running Java? Is it configured to have the TCP/IP server protocol enabled and listening on port 1433?